# Using Mechanize to login to Bing on Python 2.7.5

Tags: python-2.7, automation, mechanize, bing

I am trying to use Python 2.7.5 and the [mechanize library](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to create a program that logs me into my Microsoft account on [bing.com](http://www.bing.com).  To start out I have created this program to print out the names of the forms on this webpage, so I can reference them in later code. My current code is this (sorry about the long URL):

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Firefox')]

br.open("https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1375231095&rver=6.0.5286.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:<%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2FPassport.aspx%3Frequrl%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252f&lc=1033&id=264960&bk=1375231423")
print(br.title)

forms_printed = 0
for form in br.forms():
    print form
    forms_printed += 1
if forms_printed == 0:
    print "No forms to print!"
```

Despite the fact that when I visit the webpage in Firefox I see the username and password form, when I run this code, the result always is "No forms to print!"  Am I using mechanize wrong here, or is the website intentionally stopping me from finding those forms? Any tips and/or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to read the HTML that you are recieving you will see that webpage requires javascript.

Example:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Firefox')]

page = br.open("https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1375231095&rver=6.0.5286.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:<%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2FPassport.aspx%3Frequrl%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252f&lc=1033&id=264960&bk=1375231423")
print page.read()
print(br.title)

forms_printed = 0
for form in br.forms():
    print form
    forms_printed += 1
if forms_printed == 0:
    print "No forms to print!"
```

Output:

```
Microsoft account

JavaScript required to sign in
Microsoft account requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser either does not support JavaScript, or scripts are being blocked.

To find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, or to allow scripts, see the browser's online help.
```

See [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793414/mechanize-and-javascript) about that