# Can't login using mechanize from python. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm trying to use mechanize in python to login to this site: https://login.haaretz.co.il/
On the surface, it looks like a 2-phase login process, same as google, but following receipts for google login via mechanize gets me nowhere. After submit()-ing the browser seems to remain on the same page, with a single form containing the single userName control.
What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> br = mechanize.Browser()
>>> br.open('https://login.haaretz.co.il/')
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x7f53bfbc4a00 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x7f53bfbc4580 whose fp = <_io.BufferedReader name=3>>>
>>> 
>>> br.select_form(nr=0)
>>> 
>>> print(br.form)
<GET https://login.haaretz.co.il/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(userName=)>
  <IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>>
>>> br['userName']='my_email@gmail.com'
>>> resp = br.submit()
>>> # and after submitting I'm back a square one
>>> print(br.forms()[0])
<GET https://login.haaretz.co.il/?userName=my_email%40gmail.com application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(userName=)>
  <IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>>
>>>
```

Is this hopeless? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the login process depends on JavaScript. If the login depends on JavaScript you won't get the results you want with Mechanize. See [Mechanize and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5793414/1913726)

The script tag at xpath `'body/script[2]'` has a JavaScript object with `'loginSuccess': False` key:value pair. Therefore my guess is that the login requires JavaScript.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it is correct. Thank you.